# Hashtable traversal order

Tags: java, hashtable, traversal

I understand the hash table documentation does not guarantee insertion or comparison order. However is it possible for me to get the same order on every iteration of the workflow.

Background info
I have written a lot of code in Java and I am fine with whatever order, however for the purposes of testing, I want the order to be consistent on every run.

For example,

```
digraph {
SmartTV_On -> {Off SmartTV_Off }
Off -> {SmartTV_Off }
SmartTV_Off -> {SmartTV_On }
}

digraph {
Off -> {SmartTV_Off }
SmartTV_On -> {Off SmartTV_Off }
SmartTV_Off -> {SmartTV_On }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashtable is obsolete, you'd use HashMap.

For this specific question, `LinkedHashMap` guarantees traversal in insertion oder. `TreeMap` guarantees traversal in a provided comparison-based ordering (e.g., that if you add keys 1, 5, 2, 9, and 3 in that order, it comes back out in 1,2,3,5,9.